# Error when uploading Image to user when registering?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern, iformfile

**I am trying to upload the profile picture for my user when registering, but the error "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request" happens, what is this and how can I fix it. I have successfully loaded the image for the Index page, but my Register got the error as shown below. Here is my code**

**Error Picture**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLzSP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that you did not register the implementation of `IProfileRepository`. Please, check if you are doing something like below, in you `Startup`:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IProfileRepository, ProfileRepository>()
```

If you are not, I believe that's the cause. The important error message is actually the "Unable to resolve service..." phrase, shown in the image :)

Comment: As if I forgot, it seems to me the job is making me tired. Thank you <3.